# Como resgatar a string de conexão do App.config de outro projeto?

Tags: c#, app.config

Tenho essas strings de conexão no `App.config` **de outro projeto**:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConexaoTeste1" 
    connectionString="RGF0YSBTb3VyY2U9JCQkXFNRTEVYUFJFU1M7SW5pdGlhbCBDYXRhbG9nPXRlc3RlOw==" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

   <add name="ConexaoTeste2" 
    connectionString="RGF0YSBTb3VyY2U9dGVzdGU7UGVyc2lzdCBTZWN1cml0eSBJbmZvPVRydWU7" 
    providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Esse outro projeto não está no meu computador. Está na rede.

Como resgato o valor de `ConexaoTeste2` no **meu projeto**?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione referência `System.Configuration` no seu projeto e faça:

```
string conexao = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["ConexaoTeste2"].ConnectionString;
```

---

Sobre o fato de o `App.config` ser remoto: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785541/accessing-another-projects-app-config-properties) tem um bom motivo para não fazer dessa forma, e tem também algumas alternativas.

Comment: Jovem, ele disse há alguns minutos atrás que não é isso que precisa.

Comment: Conforme coloquei na pergunta, o config é remoto, tem toda uma questão de permissão de acesso, o problema é um pouco mais cabeludo.

Comment: Que doideira. Quando fui responder não tinha aparecido nenhuma resposta, @jbueno . Não foi por querer.

Comment: @ROBERTOALBINOJUNIOR Não tinha visto. Editei a resposta.

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Eu tinha apagado a minha, eu só restaurei pra que você pudesse ver os comentários.

Comment: @jbueno editei a pergunta. Tá em análise. Deixei mais direta e explícita sobre o fato de ser remoto.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema com o código abaixo, ignorando o arquivo como config e tratando ele como um xml normal, percorri o documento, encontrei o nó que precisava alterar e funcionou:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("\\server\\configs\\teste.exe.config");
xml.SelectNodes("configuration/connectionStrings/add").Item(1).Attributes["connectionString"].Value = "foi";
xml.Save("\\server\\configs\\teste.exe.config");
```